# enable dexoptions based on buildtype android gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use the incremental dex option but because its still experimental I only want it enabled when doing debug builds.  However, I can't find a way to reference the current buildType in the context of the dex options.

Something like this, is it possible?

```
android {
    ....
    dexOptions{
      if(buildType.name == 'debug') incremental = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I found a solution. Builds *seem* faster but I don't see any log messages to indicate incremental dex is working.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == 'debug'){
        variant.dex.enableIncremental = true
        variant.dex.dexOptions.incremental = true
        variant.dex.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you measure build times?
http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:profiling_build

Also, when you're building a release build you could just do a full 'gradle clean build', instead of disabled incremental per build type.

Comment: there is alos a android gradle plugin to measure build times..godot

Comment: I can confirm this does work, thanks for you comments guys. Confirmation by getting the constant build errors due to incremental that they say might happen.